# Access list of forms from WPF application

Tags: wpf

I've got a WPF application, that is linking w/ another assembly that contains Windows Forms.  I know in WPF I can use code like the following to iterate through the list of open WPF windows, but is there a way from the WPF app that I can iterate through the list of Forms from the other assembly?

```
foreach (Window w in App.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window is MyWindow)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way from the WPF app that I can iterate through the list of Forms from the other assembly?

The forms in the other assembly are just types. You can iterate through the public types of a referenced assembly using reflection:

```
var forms = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetReferencedAssemblies()
    .Select(x => Assembly.Load(x))
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .Where(x => x == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form))
    .ToList();
```

If you want to keep track of the currently open forms, you could use some kind of global collection to which you add the forms as you show them:

```
public static class ApplicationService
{
    //add each form that you open to this collection
    public static List<System.Windows.Forms.Form> OpenForms { get; } = new List<System.Windows.Forms.Form>();
}
```

Comment: Just make sure you remove the form from `OpenForms` when it closes, or you will prevent it from getting collected.

Comment: Yes, of course the OpenForms collection should be kept in sync with the currently opened forms, i.e. you add a form to the collection when you open it and you remove it from the collection when you close it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This looks promising, however, it appears to be returning a list of types, not a list of forms.  Can you show me how to modify this to get forms instead?  Sorry, I'm kind of a linq newbie.

Comment: Form is just a class that you are creating instances of like any other class. Referencing an assembly where there are some Form classes defined doesn't magically create any Form instances for you. So your last question doesn't make much sense I am afraid.

Comment: Yes, I understand the list will be empty until a form is created.  But the objective was to get a list of Forms, and the code as it is written, returns List of System.Type  I'm trying to iterate through the list and it gives me a compile error.

Comment: Once again: There is no list of forms. There is a list of form *types*.